# Не могу сделать приложение JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

Сделал приложение на JavaFX решил "скомпоновать" в приложение.
Работаю в Intellij IDEA лицензия, когда хочу создать модуль в Artifacts JavaFX Applicaton, при выборе класса пишет, что "ничего, чтобы показать".(скриншот прикреплён)[image: скриншот проблемы]Во второй вкладке указывал на свой класс, но не мог его выбрать, просто "OK" не загорался.Путь в 1-ой вкладке я указывал, но при запуске ругался, что не может найти класс. Не знаю что и делать молодому программисту.

Comment: Просто руками путь пропиши до класса main, это баг версии.

Comment: Как мне путь прописать?

Comment: В смысле как? Копируешь путь до места где у тебя маин класс лежит и вставляешь в это поле, не выбираешь через кнопку путь, а копи пастом втыкаешь. Ну или руками пропиши.